# Is there a way to control the width and height of an entire web page in IE using CSS only?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border

Is there a way to control the width and height of an entire web page in IE using CSS only? I ask, because IE for some reason refuses to play nice.

http://kaboomlabs.com/PDI/test.php?id=1

This page shows everything on IE as one page, but when I go to print it, it prints on one page, and the other is blank.  There is not enough data to push onto two pages, also make sure your header and footer is off. Or there maybe two pages...

Mind you, you may have to view this in compatibility mode, I have yet to figure out why, if anyone can tell me why to that it would be greatly appreciated as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is all the negative tops.  They still add size to the body.  You want to use floats instead of forcing negative locations.

Comment: Oy...ok.

Only question is that if I do a float, will the error messages be obscured by the floating panes then?

Comment: @MattRidge - depends on where they are.  There are other solutions to that.  In general, if you start needing negative margins on things, you're doing something wrong.  Occasionally, there's no other choice, but for a simple layout like yours, it's a huge red flag.

Comment: that is what I thought too, hence why I was asking.  In any case, I need to work on the form some to get it working correctly now, but it's appreciative for the help.